# random numbers with pointers (C)

Tags: c, pointers, random, numbers

I want to create random numbers within a range (0 - a) and return them with the pointer b and c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void random (int a, int *b, int *c)
{
    srand(time(0));
    *b = rand()%(a+1);
    *c = rand()%(a+1);
    printf("%i%i", *b, *c);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10; // upp
    int* b;
    int* c;
    random (a, b, c);
}
```

The Code works, although my executable crashes right after the random().

Any ideas why it crashes?

Comment: `b` and `c` are pointers... you need to point them to something before you can dereference them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the pointers to point to actual integers. An easy way to do that is to declare `b` and `c` as `int` and then pass their addresses, like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10; // upp
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    random (a, &b, &c);
}
```

Comment: Not completely. You still need to move srand() outside of your function and put it into main() where it belongs, unless you only plan to call that function once ever.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker That's a good point. I was really just looking at resolving the crash. Making the code work correctly is the next step.

Comment: you're right, but I have to call it just once. It has to be in random(), because a protected main calls it.